# Get value in closure Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, closures, laravel-8

Can I pass attributes to closure from the form which won't be included in DB?
Currently, in model I'm only getting attributes from migration file (or values from the fillable array)

My code:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new UserAccessScope);
    static::creating(function ($model){
        dd($model);
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not best practice, but you can use request() method to get request fields.

Comment: Where I need to define request? Because I tried add as a param to booted function, to add instead $model and add as a use like the comment below showed. Not a single way worked

Answer (score 0):

Yes can pass attributes to closure using the `use` keyword. For Example, like following:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    parent::boot();
    $test = "This is a test";
    static::addGlobalScope(new UserAccessScope);
    static::creating(function ($model) use ($test){
        echo $test;
        dd($model);
    });
}
```

Comment: But how can I change this static test string to my attribute from form? Where I need to defin request?

Answer (score 0):

Use request() helper - but it is not best practice.

```
protected static function booted()
{
  parent::boot();
  static::addGlobalScope(new UserAccessScope);
  static::creating(function ($model) use ($test){
    $data = request()->input();
    dd($data);
  });
}
```